# Enviar id de botão por ajax para fazer atualização no banco

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Boa noite galera,

Sou iniciante na área, e peço que me ajudem, tenho uma table trazendo resultados do banco de dados em php, em um dos campos tem um botão que guarda os **id** (chave primaria) e ao clicar nesse botão chama uma janela modal, e queria acrescentar que ao clicar neste botão de id, ele atualizasse um status de um campo de 0 para 1 no banco de dados. Estou tentando atualizar com ajax, mas não está dando certo, quem puder me ajudar agradeço mto.

Meu codigo está assim:

```
 //Tabela
          <table class="table">      

            <thead>
              <tr>  
              <td><center>Visualizar</center></td>

              <td><center>De</center></td>

              <td><center>Assunto</center></td>

              <td><center>Data</center></td>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <?php
                include "config.php";
                $stmt = $db->prepare("select id,msg_assunto,msg_text,lida_para from mensagens");
                $stmt->execute();
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                  if($row > 0){ 
                ?>
                <tr>   
                  <td><center><button type="button" id="btn-destaque" class="btn btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLRForm<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="img\pesquisa.png"></button></center></td>              
                  <td><?php echo $row['msg_de']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['msg_assunto']?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>

//ajax
                 <script>
 $("#btn-destaque").click(function () { //Quando o botão destaque for pressionado
var idAnun = $row['id']; //Aqui id do botão
$.ajax({
    method: "post", //Escolhe o método de envio
    url: "/fetch.php", //O endereço do script php que fará o update
    data: {id: idAnun} //Envio da ID do anuncio e a ação (ativar)

}).done(function (answer) {
    alert("sucesso");

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("falhou");
});
});
 </script>
```

Meu fetch.php:

```
<?php

 include("config.php");

 if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != 0) { //$_POST['id'] != 0 (em caso de tabela auto incremento o id será do tipo inteiro e nunca será iniciada em 0) isso em MySQL não sei outros Bancos de dados
$db = connectdb(); //função do "script_BD.php"

$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE mensagens SET lida='1' WHERE id=:id");
$update->bindValue(":id",$_POST['id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute(); // executa update;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está fazendo requisições AJAX que utilizam protocolo [HTTP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) com linguagem JavaScript no frontend:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post", //Escolhe o método de envio
    url: "/fetch.php", //O endereço do script php que fará o update
    data: {id: idAnun} //Envio da ID do anuncio e a ação (ativar)

}).done(function (answer) {
    alert("sucesso");

}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("falhou");
});
```

Seria interessante testar o envio dessas requisições e quais são as [respostas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) obtidas no envio dessas requisições para o servidor. Para isso, pode utilizar algumas ferramentas de teste de requisições HTTP, uma bem famosa é o [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Em que parte está havendo o 'erro'? Tente debugar utilizando DevTools do browser que está utilizando, normalmente a tecla F12 habilita essa ferramenta. Acesse a aba 'Network', lá será possível visualizar as requisições que a página está fazendo.

[image: Chrome DevTools]

> Antes de resolver precisamos entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Obrigado consegui identifcar o erro e arrumei, mto obrigado!